# Replace html permanently

Tags: php, javascript

I have a html file that has two buttons, approve and reject. I want that if someone clicks on the approve button, I want the box to disappear and display a message PERMANENTLY.

By permanently I mean that it should not return the box when I refresh the page.

Is it possible with JS or PHP or anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: probably. what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, presumably when someone clicks one of those buttons, you store a value somewhere indicating their action.  You would normally check if the user has previously performed this action (or if it otherwise makes sense to display the buttons) and just not output them from your PHP script in that case.

Without more details about your code it'll be impossible to provide any more help than this.

Comment: Oh! How do I check if the user has performed the action earlier? Thanks

Comment: Well, if you store the action in a database, you would check the database.  It's entirely up to what you do when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had this idea. But as I am new to web development, could you tell me how I could check the database periodically? Thanks.

Comment: You would check the database when you output the page in PHP and decide there whether to even output the buttons to the client.

Comment: Your help is highly appreciated. can you provide me with a link that would help me further for checking th database?Thanks.

Comment: Not really.  If you are using a database, you will already know how to query it and store data in it.  It sounds like you are biting off a lot more than you can chew all at once.

Comment: Oh I do know how to query a database and store data in it. So to sum it all up, you mean to say that once a user clicks on a button, I store the value in the database and the next time he logs in, I query the database and if return is true, I display something else. right?

Comment: Or the next time you display the page, yes.  As you have not provided much detail there's not really much more I can explain.

Comment: Best Answer and really helpful. At least not like the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible with JS or PHP or anything else?

Yes.

For a more detailed answer supply a more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to store a cookie that you can check if they clicked or you need to store a list of IP's and what they clicked. That's the hard part

Hiding and displaying the box is as easy as using jquery and the onclick element in html.

Edit:
I agree with the above answer without more details it is hard to provide a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

js will not be able to do something like this by itself.  you need some sort of back end server processing or a cookie that will detect the user when they go to the page and then save their button click in a server side db or client side cookie... then when the user comes back it checks the back end data source or the client side cookie and makes the changes either client side with js or server side with php

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. How do I check the database? With SELECT OR WHAT? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'll need to set a cookie when you put up the message. That's only permanent as long as they keep the cookie, though. For real permanence you'll need to associate the message state with their login/customer info and retrieve that every time they come back to the site. Which means you'll have to force a login before they get to the form.

The problem with trying to do something dynamic, then make it permanent, but only for that user, is that you have to get over the statelessness of the web. You have no idea who you're dealing with from one visit to the next. To get over that, you either need to tag them (by setting a cookie) so you'll recognize them on their next visit, or you need to make them identify themselves (by forcing a login).

Comment: Great info. i plan to use the database method and yeah I will force them to log in. But how do i check the database every time they log in? Which function? SELECT or What? Thanks. BY select i mean, SELECT * FROM USERS...OR SOMETHING ELSE. THANK YOU

Comment: You can check their message status while you're checking their login credentials. It might go something like this: SELECT message_status, username FROM logins WHERE userID=(submitted ID) and pw = (submitted password). But really it's totally down to how your table is set up and whether you put the message status into that table or some other one.

Comment: BTW: I'm assuming that you already know how to do a database transaction in PHP. If not, you'll need to check out a tutorial or something to get up to speed on that.